# Entity Framework Contains() only if non-null int

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I think this is right but want to check as I'm still not totally comfortable with EF and so am still sometimes writing non-optimal queries.

For the classes:

```
public class Country : IOrganization
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Campaign>? Campaigns { get; private set; }
}

public class Campaign : IOrganization
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public State? State { get; private set; }
    public int? StateId { get; set; }

    public Country? Country { get; private set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

Every campaign is owned by a State or a Country. Never both, never neither.

For a list of Countries (that I'm about to delete) I need to get the associated list of child Campaigns. So I'm doing the following, checking for a non-null CountryId and then using Contains().

```
List<Country> deletedCountries = ChangeTracker.Entries<Country>()
    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    .Select(e => e.Entity).ToList();

List<Campaign> campaignsIndirectDelete = await Campaigns
        .Where(campaign => campaign.CountryId != null)
        .Where(campaign => deletedCountries
            .Select(country => country.Id)
            .Contains(campaign.CountryId!.Value))
        .ToListAsync();
```

Is this the most efficient way to accomplish this?

**Update:**

The above code is in my DbContext.SaveChanges()/SaveChangesAsync(). It's there to handle deletes where Entity Framework can't correctly handle cascading deletes. (Please avoid discussion in this question about the best way to structure models so Entity Framework can cascade deletes as that is off-topic to this question.)

I need these lists to first delete a child collection in each. Then I delete the collections objects too. So that constrains what I can do.

Comment: Why are you doing this? ChangeTracker is an internal implementation detail. If you want to load related entities, either use `Inlude` to [eagerly load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) relations when loading the root classes, or use [explicit loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit) if you want to load only a few related entities.

Comment: Instead of writing what's essentially a JOIN between Country and Campain, you could write `db.Country.Include(c=>c.Campaigns).Where(c=>... country deletion criteria...).ToList()`. This will load both the entities that need to be deleted *and* their campaigns. After that, you can call `RemoveRange` or `Remove` on the countries. Or you could revers this, to load *campaigns* whose countries fill the criteria: `db.Campaigns.Where(c=>c.Country. .....)`. In EF Core 7+ you could then use batch delete with the country IDs instead of loading all country data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just updated to provide more context. Good idea about the Include() as I do need a specific collection of each of these and should get it at the same time. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems to be correct, but it's overcomplicating the problem. Since you have not shared the code of the actual delete, but only the part which determines what needs to be deleted, it's difficult to comment on your actual deletion from the perspective of efficiency.

Yet, the absolute most efficient removal is that which translates to something like

```
delete from campaign where CountryId in (1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
update campaign set IsDeleted = 1 where CountryId in (1, 2, 3)
```

Yet, sometimes you do not win that much by improving efficiency. So, before you are to optimize efficiency make sure that you actually have an efficiency problem to fix.

Now, if you want to simplify your code, then you could specify

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

for your `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, so, if you are deleting the record for real (rather than soft-deleting it by marking a deleted field as true), then the RDBMS will perform the deletion automatically in the background and you will have nothing to resolve, unless you really have a performance issue.

If you have an IsDeleted field for countries, then you can also `update`/`delete` the campaigns to manually cascade your deletion. You can also use a trigger upon the change of an `IsDeleted` field of `Country` records to update the campaigns associated to it accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I believe I need those objects to first delete their children. I am putting together another question that is as simple as possible showing my situation and why I think I need to cascade deletes myself. If there's a way around that - that will be wonderful. thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DavidThielen you can do it with a before trigger. That's executed just before the removal. Or, you can `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Ok, I put up what's driving the need in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409995/why-cant-entity-framework-handle-cascade-deletes-on-a-maybe-child). And as best I can tell, means I can't do `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: @DavidThielen quite an interesting problem. Looking into it.